# regular expression to restrict zero

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want a regular expression which allow only digits from 1 to 9999.It should restrict all other characters symbols and all.
I have tried `^\d+$`. But it is not working

Comment: Begging is so unbecoming my friend.

Comment: why is Regex so imp in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^0*(?!\d{5,}$)(?!0+$)\d+$
```

But better to parse the string to int and then compare the value..

follow **KISS** principle

Answer (score 4):

It's going to be a bit ugly if you insist on doing it entirely in Regexs. The only thing I can think of is something like: `^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}$` (a digit from 1 to 9 followed by 0 to 3 digits from 0 to 9).

Comment: `{0,3}`, not `{0-3}`, of course. :)

Comment: ^[1-9][0-9]{0-3}$..its not working

Comment: @AnilkumarM: Yes - it needs to be `{0,3}` or `{,3}`, not `{0-3}`.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: At least as I read it, he wants to prohibit those (but please leave the downvote in place -- it gets my rep back to a multiple of 5, where I want it).

Answer (score 1):

You really dont need regex for this,

So the Non-Regex way

```
        string myNum = "5000";

        int num;

        if (Int32.TryParse(myNum, out num) && (num >= 1 && num <= 9999))
        {
            //condition validated
        }
```

And the

Regex Way

```
bool foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(myNum, "^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$");
```

Comment: eww, better use Int32.TryParse

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ - try is why i prefer Int32.TryParse

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ - 0+[1-9][0-9]{0,3} will that work?

Comment: There is a difference between parsing the number and regex is that, parsing number doesn't check for leading zeros. But we can combine 2 methods - check for leading 0 with regex, then parse the number and compare for the range.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a character class.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{,3}$
```

Comment: What about the number 10?

Comment: Going brain dead. The edit will allow 1-9 for the first char and optionally 0-9 for up to 3 more chars.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek: Check whether the language allow you to specify {,m}. In some language, it is consider invalid regex syntax.

Comment: @nhahtdh - The answer would be yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx (Given example: ab{,2}c matches ac, abc, abbc, or aabbcc)

Comment: @ErikNedwidek: Alright. .NET regex is pioneering in its own way... (I don't say that it is bad or good, though)